# How to create multi-level sidebar for dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I starting am developing bootstrap4. and am trying to make a dashboard. I have found [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) but it is for bootstrap 3. I understand how to make a side bar with bootstrap but i can not replicate how to do the multi level dropdown that they working in their sidebar. I have tried but not found any how too or snippets.  Does anyone know any sources or an explanation on how i reproduce these smooth animations and drop downs in the sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are interest there exists a  plugin that assists with allowing multy level menus http://mm.onokumus.com/index.html